# How can I show template dropdown in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I have created a new custom post type in wordpress using **`register_post_type()`** function But when I click on **add new** in right side the editor not showing **template** choose option as you can see in **Screenshot_01.png**. In **Screenshot_2** you can see the default add post option has the **template** choose option. How can I get that option without using plugin.
Here is my exiting code for creating custom post type.

```
function short_story_type(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'storys', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'story', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'storys', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'story', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives' => __( 'story Archives', 'textdomain' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'story Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent story:', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All storys', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New story', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New story', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit story', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update story', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View story', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'View storys', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search story', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into story', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this story', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'storys list', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'storys list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter storys list', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'story', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-album',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'story', $args );




}
add_action('init', 'short_story_type');
```

Comment: there are no screenshots in your question, can you edit it to include them or remove the references?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where these screenshots you're talking about have gone, no matter, i think i know the problem.

You simply need to add support for the post type in the templates you want to be able to attach by adjusting the `Template Post Type:` line for the appropriate template files in your theme.

**Example**

```
Template Post Type: post, books, movies
```

The dropdown should then appear in the editor like it does for posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
'`capability_type' => 'post',`
```

to

```
'capability_type' => 'page',
```